# Bloomberg BlpData Instantiation error

Tags: bloomberg

Instantiating BlpData is returning me an error. **"The specified path is invalid"**

I have the **C:\blp\API\activex\blpdatax.dll** available which is the library used to instantiate BlpData. But still I see an error that path is invalid.

```
Private objDC As BlpData

Private Sub Instantiate() 
' Purpose   : Creates the BlpData Object to retrieve Bloomberg Data'
        Set objDC = New BlpData
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume this is VBA - have you checked your project references?

Comment: Hi, this is vba code. Can u please clarify where can I check project references. This snippet works on one of my colleagues pc but not on other. That is throwing me off guard

Comment: In the VBA Editor > Tools > References and verifying that you don't have any "MISSING" errors and that the Bloomberg lib is selected.

Comment: Hi Assylias.. thanks.. I checked the project references. All the bloomberg references lib are checked.. Interesting thing is this is a shared Access DB(VBA) on network drive, which is accessed by multiple people in my team. One person has no issues creating "BlpData" instance but other person has an issue throwing into debug mode stopping with this error "Automation error. The specified path is invalid"

Answer (score 1):

Bloomberg files are located in **C:/blp** folder by default. If this directory is not in the **environment system path variable** VBA cannot locate the blpdatax.dll

In my case c:/blp is in the path but there was a syntax error in the path variable of another directory which was blocking the code to find the dll.

So check if all directories listed in your path variable are syntactically updated.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, as Srujan mentioned it was a problem with the PATH environment variable. There was another directory in quotes, i.e. C:\;**"C:\foo\bar\"**;C:\windows. Removing the unneeded quotes (semi-colon is the separator) fixed the error.

(Would have posted as a comment above but not enough rep.)